# cod JSON to Array PHP I want a correct example

Tags: php, json, post

This is the Json code

```
{"data":{"user":{"first_name":"xx","last_name":"xx","email":"xx","countryOfResidence":"GB","country":"LK","nationality":"LK"},"billing_address":{"line1":"xx","city":"xx","postal_code":"xx","country":"LK"},"shipping_address":{"first_name":"xx","last_name":"xx","line1":"xx","city":"xx","postal_code":"xx","country":"LK"},"phone":{"type":"Mobile","number":"xx","countryCode":"94"},"marketing_optin":true,"shipping_address_validation":false,"poma_flow":false,"prox_flow":false,"testParams":{},"content_identifier":"LK:en:2.0.287:signupTerms.signupC","card":{"type":"MASTERCARD","number":"xx","security_code":"xx","expiry_month":"xx","expiry_year":"xx"},"skipInitiateAuth":true},"meta":{"token":"xx","calc":"xx","csci":"xx","locale":{"country":"LK","language":"en"},"state":"ui_checkout_guest","app_name":"xoonboardingnodeweb"}}
```

This is the PHP code I want to write the code in a correct way and make it work.
I want to know where my fault is. Can anyone correct this file from​ me?
Please help with this example clearly.

```
                $link = "https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-7Y207450BE832821N#/checkout/guest"; 
                $post = "";  
                $s = _curl($link, json_encode($post), $cookie);



            $post = json_encode($array);
            $array = json_decode($json_string, true);
$link = "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/xoonboarding/api/onboard/guest";


                                    $post = [
        'data' => [
            'user' => [
                'first_name' => 'xx',
                'last_name' => 'xx',
                'email' => 'xx',
                'countryOfResidence' => 'GB',
                'country' => 'LK',
                'nationality' => 'lk',
            ],
            'billing_address' => [
                'line1' => 'xx',
                'city' => 'xx',
                'postal_code' => 'xx',
                'country' => 'lk',
            ],
            'shipping_address' => [
                'first_name' => 'xx',
                'last_name' => 'xx',
                'line1' => 'xx',
                'city' => 'xx',
                'postal_code' => 'xx',
                'country' => 'lk',
            ],
            'phone' => [
                'type' => 'Mobile',
                'number' => 'xx',
                'countryCode' => '94',
            ],
            'marketing_optin' => true,
            'shipping_address_validation' => false,
            'poma_flow' => false,
            'prox_flow' => false,
            'testParams' => [],
            'content_identifier' => "LK:en:2.0.287:signupTerms.signupC",
            'card' => [
                'type' => 'xx',
                'number' => xx,
                'security_code' => xx,
                'expiry_month' => xx,
                'expiry_year' => xx,
            ],
            'skipInitiateAuth' => true
        ],
        'meta' => [
            'token' => xx,
            'calc' => xx,
            'csci' => xx,
            'locale' => [
                'country' => 'LK',
                'language' => 'en',
            ],
            'state' => 'ui_checkout_guest',
            'app_name' => 'xoonboardingnodeweb',
        ]
    ];

    $s = _curl($link, json_encode($post), $cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to easily visualize the structure of your JSON, and transpose it in PHP. Or you can just create a PHP variable thanks to `json_decode` with you JSON code giving in example.

```html
$link = "https://www.paypal.com/webapps/xoonboarding/api/onboard/guest";

$data = [
    'data' => [
        'user' => [
            'first_name' => 'xx',
            'last_name' => 'xx',
            'email' => 'xx',
            'countryOfResidence' => 'GB',
            'country' => 'LK',
            'nationality' => 'lk',
        ],
        'billing_address' => [
            'line1' => 'xx',
            'city' => 'xx',
            'postal_code' => 'xx',
            'country' => 'lk',
        ],
        'shipping_address' => [
            'first_name' => 'xx',
            'last_name' => 'xx',
            'line1' => 'xx',
            'city' => 'xx',
            'postal_code' => 'xx',
            'country' => 'lk',
        ],
        'phone' => [
            'type' => 'Mobile',
            'number' => 'xx',
            'countryCode' => '94',
        ],
        'marketing_optin' => true,
        'shipping_address_validation' => false,
        'poma_flow' => false,
        'prox_flow' => false,
        'testParams' => [],
        'content_identifier' => "LK:en:2.0.287:signupTerms.signupC",
        'card' => [
            'type' => 'xx',
            'number' => 'xx',
            'security_code' => 'xx',
            'expiry_month' => 'xx',
            'expiry_year' => 'xx',
        ],
        'skipInitiateAuth' => true
    ],
    'meta' => [
        'token' => 'xx',
        'calc' => 'xx',
        'csci' => 'xx',
        'locale' => [
            'country' => 'LK',
            'language' => 'en',
        ],
        'state' => 'ui_checkout_guest',
        'app_name' => 'xoonboardingnodeweb',
    ]
];

$json = json_encode($data, true);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
$ch = curl_init($link);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);                                                                
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json)]);                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Comparing the two structure, your PHP code seems to be correct. What the  HTTP request response ?

Comment: I NEED JSON to Array PHP IN example

Comment: This code I put in the first topic I want to convert to to Array PHP In order to put it in the Post box

Comment: Check my edit.. But, your request is unclear as possible. Your example just have no sense. On top of that, you're requiring the solution instead of wanting to know how it works. By the way, you're currently asking the same question in an other topic in which somebody gave you good tips.